# jQuery animate complete not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The animation itself is working but why isn't my complete function working?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/5kfbw066/1/

```js
$(".ok").animate({
height:"300px"

},{
 duration:2000
 }, {complete:function(){
alert('hey');
}
});
```

```css
.ok{
  background:blue;
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ok"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`complete` is a property just as `duration`

```js
$(".ok").animate({
  height: "300px"

}, {
  duration: 2000,
  complete: function() {
    alert('hey');
  }
});
```

```css
.ok {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ok"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`complete` callback should be passed as the method on the second param object to the [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-duration-easing-complete), not as a different object.

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5kfbw066/3/)

```
$(".ok").animate({
  height: "300px"
}, { // <--- Pass `complete` callback as part of this object.
  duration: 2000,
  complete: function() {
    alert('hey');
  }
});
```

```js
$(".ok").animate({
  height: "300px"
}, { // <--- Pass `complete` callback as part of this object.
  duration: 2000,
  complete: function() {
    alert('hey');
  }
});
```

```css
.ok {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ok"></div>
```

Or, it can also be passed as last parameter to `animate`

```
$(".ok").animate({
    height: "300px"
  }, 2000,
  function() {
    alert('hey');
  }
);
```

```js
$(".ok").animate({
    height: "300px"
  }, 2000,
  function() {
    alert('hey');
  }
);
```

```css
.ok {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ok"></div>
```